# C++: Shifting the elements of a 2D array by 1 in order to insert into the position

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, dynamic-arrays, dynamic-allocation

I wanted to know how to insert an element at a given position in a 2D dynamically allocated array of type template. If the position is larger than the size of the array, increase the array to this new position.

A value can only be inserted at the given position if the position does not store a value yet, if it does all elements need to be shifted one position forward to free the requested position.

Ps: I cannot use vectors, it needs to be a 2D array.

Here is what I have so far:

```
template <class T>
class myArrayClass
{ 
public:
    myArrayClass(int newSize) ; 
    void insert(int position, T value) ; 
private:
    T **myArray ; 
    int size ; 
    int numberOfElements ;
    void resizeArray(int increase) ;  
};
```

My implementation is as follows:

```
myArrayClass::myArrayClass(int newSize)
{
    size = newSize ; 
    myArray = new T*[size] ; 
    for (int i=0 ; i<size ; i++)
    {
      myArray[i] = new T[size] ; 
      numberOfElements++; 
    } 

   for (int j=0; j <size; j++)
   {
     for (int k=0; k<size; k++)
     {
       myArray[j][k] = 0 ; 
     }
   }  
}


void myArrayClass::resizeArray(int increase)
{
  if(size != increase)
  {
    //Call destructor
 } 

  myArray = new T *[increase] ; 

 for (int i=0; i<increase; i++)
 { 
    myArray[i] = new T[increase] ; 
   numberOfElements++ ; 
}
}

void myArrayClass::insert(int position, T value)
{
     if(position > size)
     {
        int ns = position + size ; 
        resizeArray(ns) ; 

     for (int i = 0 ; i < ns; i++)
    {

      for (int j = 0; j < ns; j++)
    { 
      if (i==position || j == position)
     {
       if(myArray[position][j] == 0) //I will repeat the same if for [i][position]
      {
        myArray[position][j] == value ; 
      }
      else 
         {
           //Code to shift elements of the array forward by 1 position
         }
     }
   }

  }
}
```

Comment: This is a strange insertion routine, does the `position` encode the 2d location correctly (i.e. row/column) or can you only ever insert at a location specified by the same value for *row or column*? Anyway your implementation is somewhat broken in that your resize will trash your existing array *before* you move.

Comment: It encodes both, one for the row and the other for the column.